# laravel passport: Request user() returning null outside auth:api middleware, and inside returning user object

Tags: php, laravel

When I am tring to get loggedin user details using auth:api middleware, it returns user object with details in my controller function.

```
api.php (with auth:api middleware returns User object)

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('users/mentor_details/{uuid}','UserController@getMentorProfileDetails');
});
```

But when I am trying to get loggedin user details outside this auth:api middleware, it returns null.

```
api.php (without auth:api middleware return null)

Route::get('users/mentor_details/{uuid}','UserController@getMentorProfileDetails');
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When the auth middleware is not provided, or is provided without specifying the guard, the default guard is used to determine the user. Unless you have changed this in your `config/auth.php` file, the default guard is the `web` guard.

So, when you go to a route that is not protected by a specific auth middleware, the user that is loaded is the one provided by the `web` guard.

Therefore, even though you may be sending the bearer token to use a specific user, the `web` guard doesn't know anything about that, and since you have no user logged in via the `web` guard, you are getting a `null` user.

You've got four options:

1. Make sure the route is protected by the `auth:api` middleware, which specifies the `api` guard. This, however, will not allow guests to access the url.
2. Change your default guard to `api` in your `config/auth.php` file. This is probably not what you want to do, especially if you do have normal web users.
3. Tell the request you want the user from the `api` guard. The `$request->user()` method takes a guard as an argument, so if you do `$request->user('api')`, it will retrieve the user using the `api` guard.
4. Get the user from the `api` guard directly: `auth()->guard('api')->user()`.

Comment: $request->user('api'); is much better, because I already have $request object in my funciton.

Comment: @patricus: great explanation mate! I finally understand a little piece of Laravel Passport I have missed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do i have to use something in header ??

Comment: You can also use the `auth` helper function passing the middleware name; `auth('api')->user();`

Answer (score 3):

The auth middleware is the one returning the user. auth:api just indicates to use the API guard. In the source code of laravel, the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php` line **62**, the function shouldUse is the one setting the Auth::user() object. Check out also `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php` shouldUse function

Answer (score 0):

override createToken() method app\Models\User.php like below.

```
public function createToken($user_id,$name, array $scopes = [])
{
    return Container::getInstance()->make(PersonalAccessTokenFactory::class)
    ->make(
        $user_id, $name, $scopes
    );
}
```

And create token as given below wherever you want and explicitly pass $user_id.

```
$user= new user();
$accessToken = $user->createToken($user_id,'authToken')->accessToken;
```

Now you will get $request->user()

Answer (score 0):

override register() method app\Exceptions\Handler.php like below-

public function register() {

```
$this->renderable(function (\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
    if ($request->is('api/*')) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Not authenticated'
        ], 401);
    }
});
```

}