# Call to a member function addBusiness() on null

Tags: laravel

I am trying to save user_id with relation i have created relation between user and business in which user can add many relationship but it displays this error

```
   My Controller 

                          $fieldsValidation = [

        'business_name' => 'required',
        'business_url' => 'required',
        'is_available' => 'required',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $fieldsValidation);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $resultArray = [
            'status' => 0,
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            'dataArray' => []
        ];
    } else {
        $business = new Business($request->all());
        Auth::user()->addBusiness()->save($business);

        $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Business Name added successfully!', 'dataArray' => $business];
    }
    return Response::json($resultArray, 200);
```

My User Model

```
    public function addBusiness()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Business','user_id','id');
}

        My Business Model 
         public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
}
```

Any help wil be appreciated

Comment: You haven't added the error you are getting.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and call `addBusiness()` method only when `Auth::user()` is not `null`.

Try this:

```
if(Auth::check()){
     Auth::user()->addBusiness()->save($business);
} else {
//user not logged in do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says you're trying to call `addBusiness()` on null. The only place I see you calling `addBusiness()` is `Auth::user()->addBusiness()`.

This means `Auth::user()` is returning null.

`Auth::user()` returns null when you're not logged in. It will also return null if you are on a route not protected by the correct `auth` middleware and you are logged in under a non-default guard. If you are on an unprotected route and you're logged in under a non-default guard (e.g. the `api` guard), you can get the user using `$request->user('api')` or `auth()->guard('api')->user()`.

Comment: My user id logged in and i dont what if my routes are according to you.

Comment: Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
Route::post('register', 'UserController@register');

Route::post('add_business',['uses' => 'BusinessController@addBusinessLogic']);

Comment: @syed1234 I'm assuming the controller logic you've shown in your question is from your `add_business` route. This route does not have the `auth` middleware applied to it.

Comment: @syed1234 [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110391/laravel-passport-request-user-returning-null-outside-authapi-middleware-and/46111430#46111430) may help you.

Comment: I am using laravel passport for api if i used auth middleware this brings to the default login laravel page

Comment: @syed If you don't want to protect the route with middleware, try using `$request->user('api')` or `auth()->guard('api')->user()` to get the user, instead of `Auth::user()`.