# How to return JSON representation of logged in user Laravel?

Tags: json, laravel

How do I return a JSON representation of the currently authenticated user? I see that Laravel `routes/api.php` has a method:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

But when I try to reach the route I get an error,

```
InvalidArgumentException
Route [login] not defined.
```

I have also tried creating my own route, but have not had success. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

#### My solution:

to solve this problem just do the following changes:

go to `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`

change the render function and remove the parent render function and instead return your own json response, like in this gist:

```
namespace App\Exceptions;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];
    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];
    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }
    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return response()->json(
            [
                'errors' => [
                    'status' => 401,
                    'message' => 'Unauthenticated',
                ]
            ], 401
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass on Header:

```
Accept: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

### missing route login

Since you were not authenticated with a valid API token the auth:api-middleware redirected to the route named 'login'.

To scaffold this route you can do

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Or do it yourself web.php

```
Route::get('login', function () {
    //
})->name('login');
```

in  and change user json retrival code to

### current user as json

In web.php put:

```
Route::middleware('auth.basic')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return Auth::user();
});
```

If you still want to put it in api.php you need to apply the 'web' middleware.

Comment: Hmmmm. I am logged in to Nova though? This is the authenticated user I want. Would it not return the same user?

Comment: Oh you are right. That is because of the middleware('auth:api') - you will need to provide a token with the request. If you do not want to authenticate as an API user, it is better to move it to web.php and change the middleware to 'auth.basic'

Comment: I have also tried without the `middleware('auth:api')`, but that doesn't seem to work either - it just returns a blank page. I am trying to ultimately use this for a Vue page, and through dev tools I am getting an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: You can read up on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110391/laravel-passport-request-user-returning-null-outside-authapi-middleware-and also will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

For someone who still needs.

1. Add to the header request

   `Accept: application/json`
2. Force or want to custom JSON response

in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` edit render function

don't forget to use: `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;` at the top file.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) { //check if exception is error of Auth
        if($request->expectsJson()){ //check if request accept json, remove it if you don't want
            return response([ //here is your custom response
                "status" => 0,
                "msg"    => "INVALID_TOKEN"
            ]);
        }
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: It's probably best to override what's returned using Laravel's renderable. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions